# Fullcalendar - conditional rendering one event

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, fullcalendar, apex

**INTRO**

Hey, I'm writing page using jquery fullcalendar to display events from my Salesforce org. I'm struggling to implement conditional rendering of events which happen to be on the exact same time in calendar, what looks like this: 
[image]

**SPECIFICATION**

The green on the left represent working hours of dentist and after clicking one of them user is redirected to fill out the form, after that there is created event which is marked as red one.

**PROBLEM**

I would like to implement function or whatever makes sense to remove, or overlap the events on the left side (green or red). Is there any specific concept I should be using ? Thanks for your time.

Here is a code which I wrote :

```js
                    function getEventData(dentistId) {
                    alert(dentistId);
                    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                        '{!$RemoteAction.CalendarController.eventData}', dentistId,
                        function(result, event){
                            if (event.status) {
                                evt =  JSON.parse(result);
                                console.log(evt);
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                                    header: {
                                        left: 'prev,next today',
                                        center: 'title',
                                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listDay',
                                    },
                                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                                        if(calEvent.editable === true) {
                                            var start = moment(calEvent.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                                            var end = moment(calEvent.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                                            jQuery('[id$=startStringField]').val(start);
                                            jQuery('[id$=endStringField]').val(end);
                                            passToController();
                                        } else {
                                         return false;
                                        }
          },
                                    eventOverlap: false,
                                    defaultDate: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today'),
                                    navLinks: true,
                                    events: evt,
                                    eventRender: function(event, element) {
                 element.qtip({
                    content: event.description
                });
            },
                                    textColor: 'white',
                                    height:650,
                                }) 
                            } else if (event.type === 'exception') { 
                                console.log(event.message);
                            } else {
                                console.log(event.message);
                            }
                        }, 
                        {escape: false}
                    );
                }
```

The result is a string in json format which represent array of events to be displayed which are then parsed:
[Json which is parsed to array of objects](http://pastebin.com/7jZajAzW)

Comment: Map the data before passing to calendar

Comment: Since you now have the entered event on your server, it would make sense to remove this other green event from your JSON before you send it to the browser.